# How to call method of child page from master page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In my web site, most of page save something in bank and for this

> I define methods for each page to **save own values**

After first release I decide to use unique button to do Save for each page and delete button in page (Something like Container form in Win-App). so  I'm define `button in master-page` for doing this. but

> **How to call method of child page from master page?**

You know, method different from each other. I think to define 'virtual-method', call it in button-Click event and override that in page but `page cs not inheritance from master-page !!!`

> **So what do I Do**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To call a content page method from master page:

Create a base class for your pages (e.g. `BasePage`) and then inherit your pages from that class. Then create a virtual method in your base class and override it in your page classes. You can then call that virtual method from the master page:

```
(cphContent.Page as BasePage).CustomMethod();
```

`cphContent` is the ID of the `ContentPlaceHolder` in your master page.

Make sure that the content page you're referring to in the master page is not null.

Comment: Wow, I have Base-page(same as you say). I test it now